# Word wrap with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I use IntelliJ IDEA, it helps me a lot in the learning process. But there is one problem: when I open 2 applications in 1 screen, the text doesn't create a new line / is not responsive according to the size of IntelliJ but extends sideways.

I want to know if there is a feature like VS Code when we click "view" it says "word wrap" when clicked the text will be responsive according to the size of the application.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer resolved your issue, you can mark it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark icon next to it. This will help others who may have the same question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Jetbrains IDEs (IntelliJ, Pycharm, Webstorm, Rider, Phpstorm, etc) have a function called soft wrap. Similar to Vs code, allows to have the same functionality to accomodate the font size.

You can enable it,

1. Pressing shift two times
2. Write "Soft Wrap"
3. Press enter

Or

1. Clicking on the line numbers
2. Click in soft wrap

Here I attached an screenshot to show how it works.

[Image in shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi1fq.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can enable "Word Wrap" by left-clicking on the line numbers area in the editor window. This will open a context menu where you can select the "Word Wrap" option, which will enable the feature and make the text responsive to the size of the application window.